# How to install Tencent Gaming Buddy on PlayOnLinux?

Tags: playonlinux

I Installed playonlinux then I tried Manual install, selected '.exe' File which I downloaded from https://syzs.qq.com/en/ , it started but after sometime while installing game it showed some error.
My Question is how do I install it successfully.

Comment: Please add the "some error" to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When tencent gaming buddy runs on Windows platform it also starts some of its services, these services are necessary for the startup of tencent gaming buddy.So if you want to start tencent gaming buddy on linux with the help of Wine/PlayOnLinux it won't start because the services needed to be launched and these crucial tencent services are meant only for the windows platform.Therefore it difficult to run Tencent Gaming Buddy on Linux :-)

Comment: "it also starts some of its services"... which services?

Comment: What you are missing here is that the whole point of "Play on Linux", "Lutris" or in one word "Wine" is so that we configure the environments such that these "services" can run. Most windows apps are not meant for Linux. In any case it would be very helpful if you could list out the services or programs that you think are the cause of this failure. We can then figure out how to make them work